Developing mobile app that opens on first touch
I am starting to develop an app. The main idea is to make a picture open on first touch (when you start the phone after inactivity/black screen) for a few seconds, and give the opportunity to the user to enter the normal functionalities after those few minimum seconds by swiping in some direction. No other standard gadget visible (e.g. no clock). Is it possible?

Basically you want to replace the lock screen?  That used to be possible back in the early 2010s. I don't think it is anymore without a rooted device.  And the lack of any ability to put a password or authentication in your idea sounds problematic for most devices.

That is a good question. Thinking about it, I would like this picture to show up after the screen is unlocked. So, first push normal. Swipe to unlock. Picture there for 3-5 seconds. The it shows up the possibility to slide again to close the picture and use the phone as normal. - My question is probably: usually we start apps by clicking on the icon. Is it possible to create an app that once in a while shows you a picture full-screen for some time?

Not easily these days.  If you wanted to do processing work every once in a while, sure.  If you want to show a UI, then that's heavily restricted when you can show a UI from the background, see https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/background-starts.  You can use an AccessibilityService, but that's probably not going to be allowed on the Play Store (if that matters to you).  You could possibly do it via system window overlays, but you'll need the user to manually enable drawing over the screen for your app

Hi Gabe, super idea you have there. Basically, let's suppose that it works as an alarm, that is set to run twice a day to remind you something to do. However, it doesn't remind you through a notification, but it actually shows you something on your screen. Would you see that feasible if put that way?

Ah, but maybe, now that I think of it more, that solution would remove the first-touch feature, that was quite important. Thing is that my Android has ha feature called Carousell, which is not that far away in concept. Only, it does not stop you for 3-5 seconds.

So, to summarize, @GabeSechan , tell me if I am wrong: presenting a picture after first-touch, after screen is unlocked, should be possible if the app runs in background, correct? To let an app run in background, you have to ask permission to the user, correct too?
